# JSON printing (treeview)

Tags: javascript, json, treeview

I have a complex json string that looks like this:

```
    {
    "id":"2016666",
    "dt":"2012",
    "object_extends":[
        {
             "extend1":{
                "id":"2016666",
                "dt":"2012",
                "active":"true",
                "object_extend":[
                    {
                        "extend2":
                        {
                            "id":"2016666",
                            "secondary":null
                        },
                        "extend3":
                         {
                            "id":"2016666",
                            "pet":"willy"
                         }

                    }
                ]
            }

        }
    ]
}
```

Now i want to print this like a tree, but when searching for days i have to modify the json(which is not a option). How can i print this in a treeview? I tried for loops but each extend can have other attributes then other objects. Hope somebody can help me with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check these out:

[How to generate Treeview from JSON data using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560960/how-to-generate-treeview-from-json-data-using-javascript)

https://github.com/lmenezes/json-tree

https://github.com/liuwenchao/aha-tree

https://github.com/AlexLibs/niTree

[https://github.com/tamirs9876/JSON.Tree.Builder -- one of my fav](https://github.com/tamirs9876/JSON.Tree.Builder)

I think visit this and use which you like:

[https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=json+tree&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=json%20tree&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)

***Edit For Your Request :***

To remove the null nodes in [https://github.com/tamirs9876/JSON.Tree.Builder -- one of my fav](https://github.com/tamirs9876/JSON.Tree.Builder) :

Cover line 8 with

```
if(data[i] != null){
}
```

in JsonTreeBuilder.js

Last state of js file is like

```
.
.
var ul = $('<ul>');
            for (var i in data) {
                var li = $('<li>');
                if(data[i] != null){
                    ul.append(li.text(i).append(generateTree(data[i])));
                }
            }
.
.
```

Comment: for jstree you have to alternate the json, which is not a option(already told that in the first post)

Comment: You are a hero! Youre fav saved me a lot of time. The only problem i have now is that is also displays keys with null values. Any idea how to change that when a value is null it does not display?

Comment: i manipulated js file for your requirement, please follow the steps in the message.

Comment: You sir, are my hero!