# Show tree structure data in select box - JQuery, jSon, Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I want to show nested data in either "Ul" and "li" or  box but have to show in tree structure.
So in Json, i am receiving folder structure and I don't know how many folders level Json file has. So I have to write my code to pull the data from JSon file and show the data as tree structure based on the levels.

I am also not sure how my JSon file should look like but i came up with this sample JSon file.
So what I need is if some one just point me to the correct direction that for achieve the functionality, what structure of JSon file i need to create and what my Ajax Jquery code should look like

**JSON file**

```
{
"folder": [
    {
    "id":"11"
    "name: "test1",
    "path": "site/test1",
    "children": [
        "12",
        "13"
        ]
    },
    {
    "id":"12",
    "name":"sub test1",
    "path":"site/test1/subtest1",
    "children":[
       "21"
       ]
    },
    {
    "id":"13",
    "name":"sub test 2",
    "path":"site/test1/subtest2",
    "children":[]
    },
    {
    "id":"21",
    "name":"sub sub test 1",
    "path":"site/test1/subtest1/subsubtest1",
    "children":[]
    },
    {
    "id":14",
    "name":"test2",
    "path":"site/test2",
    "children":[]
    }
  ]
}
```

**sample JQUERY Code**

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://localhost/web/folder.json",
        success: function(obj) {
           $.each(obj.folder, function (key, value) { // First Level
               console.log(value.name);
               $.each(value.children, function (k, v) {  // The contents inside stars
                   console.log(v);
               });
           });
        }
       });
```

Comment: Please check this, maybe it can help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27018022/json-printing-treeview/27019597#27019597

Comment: create html instead of logging to console, you are almost there